# Jquery element Fadeout on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to do fadeout when I scrolling it's working but when i scroll to the top the element be hidden 
i'm using plugin hidden

**JADE**

```
#header
.container
  #content
    h3.post-logo ACHRAF
    h1.post-behind A
    h2.title.animate.fadeInUp Développeur Mobile
    h2.title & Web
```

**JQUERY**

```
         $(window).scroll( function(){

       if($('#header:hidden'))

            $('#header').addClass('animated fadeOut');

        else
          $('#header').addClass('animated fadeInUp'); 


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily fade out and fade in with this code:

```
   if($('#header:hidden'))
        $('#header').fadeOut(100);
    else
      $('#header').fadeIn(100);
```

Comment: it's gone element when i scroll

Answer (score 0):

Try this (http://jsfiddle.net/2p4x52up/)...

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

JS...

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(e) {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#header").height()) $("#header").fadeOut(500);
    else $("#header").fadeIn(500);
});
```

CSS...

```
#header { 
  background: red; 
  height: 100px; 
  left: 0; 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
  background: gray;
}
```

Comment: can  u try with plugin :hidden ?

Comment: @achrafbans I can't because this property won't work exactly as you want. Note that my script recognizes the height of your object to work perfectly.

Comment: @Icon Portela i added two element in your exemple not work, can u use two element  ?